# How to get who is watching a stream with Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

In a voice channel, how to fetch the members watching a stream in the same voice channel using Discord.js?

It seems like `onVoiceStateUpdate` is not triggered when a user starts watching a stream.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at the Discord.js [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=streaming) and can't seem to find any events that return viewers of a stream. Hopefully in v13 they add this.

Alternatively you could get the number of people in the voice chat - would not necessarily be accurate, but it would be a possible way around it:

```js
let voiceChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.id === '<voice channel id goes here>');

message.channel.send(voiceChannel.members.size;); //sends number of users in the voicechannel
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. We only have access to who is streaming but not who is watching.

Comment: This is correct, I can't think of any way you could do it without an external process physically watching the viewers. But there is still no visual effect when a user joins a stream other than a sound.

Answer (score 0):

The voice state structure only contains a boolean value "self_stream", so it's unlikely that this is possible without changes to the discord api

https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/voice#voice-state-object-voice-state-structure